# rearrange webpage design based on device width

Tags: css, layout, flexbox, containers

quite possibly this is a duplicate for another question, if it is please close this question,

I am wondering how is it possible to have different layout for desktop view and different for mobile, please check the pictures and sorry for the bad design i used msPaint
Thanks!
[desktop view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XccGw.png)
[mobile view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwCXX.png)

Comment: Please take a look at [@media rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) to get dimensions and apply different styling where you want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Media Queries: How to target desktop, tablet, and mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370690/media-queries-how-to-target-desktop-tablet-and-mobile)

Answer (score 0):

you must use media query. It's better to share your source code but you can use this link for more information: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp